# Missing properties when inferring props from component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

So basically, I found myself using this pattern a lot with Material UI to avoid using inline styles or the hook or hoc styling api :

```js
const TestStepper = styled(props => (
  <MobileStepper classes={{ progress: "progress" }} {...props} />
))(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: "transparent",
  "& > .progress": {
    width: "100%",
    marginRight: theme.spacing(3)
  }
}));
```

I cannot rely on a stable `MuiMobileStepper-progress` class [because I have nested themes](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#with-material-ui-core), so I use this trick to get stable nested selectors.

I wanted to encapsulate this behaviour in a utility function :

```js
export function styledNested<
  P extends { classes: Record<string, string> },
  C extends Array<keyof P["classes"]>
>(Component: ComponentType<P>, ...classes: C) {
  return styled((props: P) => (
    <Component
      {...props}
      classes={classes.reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: key }), {})}
    />
  ));
}
```

But when trying it :

```js
const TestStepper = styledNested(
  MobileStepper,
  "progress"
)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: "transparent",
  "& > .progress": {
    width: "100%",
    marginRight: theme.spacing(3)
  }
}));
```

I get the following TS error :

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(props: MobileStepperProps) => Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<{ classes: Record<string, string>; }>'.
 Type '(props: MobileStepperProps) => Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{ classes: Record<string, string>; }>'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
   Type 'PropsWithChildren<{ classes: Record<string, string>; }>' is missing the following properties from type 'MobileStepperProps': backButton, nextButton, steps
```

**[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-sun-4z5bp?file=/src/App.tsx)**

How could I fix this ?

Comment: Can you post this as a code sandbox link?

Comment: @dwjohnston https://codesandbox.io/s/old-sun-4z5bp?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `ctrl + click` in the `classes` prop when writing a `<MobileStepper ...` tag, the IDE takes you to the `StyledComponentProps` interface, so it seems that's the correct interface to extend from:

`P extends StyledComponentProps,`

But then you'll have a problem with `C` being `never[]` type because `StyledComponentProps` has `clasess` as an optional prop, this is solved by using [Required](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) over `P` when getting the keys

`C extends Array<keyof Required<P>["classes"]>`

https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-star-zm7lx?file=/src/App.tsx